# Does the Chrome developer console have any aliases?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm writing a userscript for my own use on a certain website, which will run in Chrome (since that's my preferred browser). Some of the website's javascript apparently (re)defines `console` for its own purposes, thus preventing me from issuing my own `console.log` commands to the Chrome developer console from my userscript.

**Is there some other alias I can use to access the Chrome developer `console`?**

(Note that `window.console` will of course not work, since the website's definition of `console` is in global scope, hence my problem in the first place.)

Comment: @user113215 Right you are. That solves my problem. Flagging this as duplicate.

Comment: You could also overwrite it (again) with another type of logging mechanism. For example, that's how [jsconsole.com](http://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging.html) remote debugging works.